# Count the number a string exists in dataframe column with nested dataframes

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below which in column `genres` has nested dataframes with 3 columns. I wonder how can I find how many times the word `"Pop"` is displayed in the column `name` of all nested dataframes that exist in column `genres`

```
dat<-structure(list(name = c("Easy On Me", "All I Want For Christmas Is You", 
"Overseas (feat. Central Cee)", "Last Christmas", "Shivers"), 
    releaseDate = c("2021-10-15", "1994-10-29", "2021-11-18", 
    "1984-01-01", "2021-09-09"), kind = c("songs", "songs", "songs", 
    "songs", "songs"), artistId = c("262836961", "91853", "1240341559", 
    "548421", "183313439"), artistUrl = c("https://music.apple.com/gb/artist/adele/262836961", 
    "https://music.apple.com/gb/artist/mariah-carey/91853", "https://music.apple.com/gb/artist/d-block-europe/1240341559", 
    "https://music.apple.com/gb/artist/wham/548421", "https://music.apple.com/gb/artist/ed-sheeran/183313439"
    ), artworkUrl100 = c("https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music115/v4/73/6d/7c/736d7cfb-c79d-c9a9-4170-5e71d008dea1/886449666430.jpg/100x100bb.jpg", 
    "https://is4-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music124/v4/c6/b7/27/c6b727f7-3a32-6b43-cee2-05bb71daf1cf/dj.itfmdeif.jpg/100x100bb.jpg", 
    "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music126/v4/2e/63/01/2e6301ee-905d-5ae8-c989-eaf9d8e7e6ae/21UM1IM30658.rgb.jpg/100x100bb.jpg", 
    "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/47/55/0c/47550cd6-7ef5-bf86-c194-c7695d63c759/dj.xuditatj.jpg/100x100bb.jpg", 
    "https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/c5/d8/c6/c5d8c675-63e3-6632-33db-2401eabe574d/190296491412.jpg/100x100bb.jpg"
    ), genres = list(structure(list(genreId = c("14", "34"), 
        name = c("Pop", "Music"), url = c("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id14", 
        "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id34")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
        structure(list(genreId = c("34", "21", "17", "15", "14"
        ), name = c("Music", "Rock", "Dance", "R&B/Soul", "Pop"
        ), url = c("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id34", 
        "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id21", "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id17", 
        "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id15", "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id14"
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L)), structure(list(
            genreId = c("18", "34"), name = c("Hip-Hop/Rap", 
            "Music"), url = c("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id18", 
            "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id34")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2), 
        structure(list(genreId = c("14", "34", "17"), name = c("Pop", 
        "Music", "Dance"), url = c("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id14", 
        "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id34", "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id17"
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L)), structure(list(
            genreId = c("14", "34"), name = c("Pop", "Music"), 
            url = c("https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id14", 
            "https://itunes.apple.com/gb/genre/id34")), class = "data.frame", row.names = 1:2))), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `sum(dplyr::bind_rows(dat$genres)['name'] == 'Pop')`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total number of times the word `Pop` appears in the genres;

```
library(tidyverse)

sum(bind_rows(dat$genres)['name'] == 'Pop')
[1] 4
```

if you want the number of times in each nested dataframe:

```
 map_dbl(dat$genres, ~sum(.x['name']=='Pop'))
[1] 1 1 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
mapply(`%in%`, "Pop", lapply(dat$genres, `[[`, "name"))
#   Pop  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA> 
#  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```